# Trainable Predictive Typing with Phrase suggestions for Business

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, productivity, machine-learning, autocomplete

I would like to find a program that suggests phrases that are commonly used *by our business* as the user starts typing them, similar to Gmail's "Smart Compose" feature.

This could be an installed program that suggests phrases in any text input field (sort of like iOS's keyboard, except for phrases instead of single words, and for MS Windows), or a web app where the person composes the report on a web page, then copies it to the appropriate place.

## Background

- Our business writes reports, all day, every day. We have about 500 people writing these reports.
- The reports have a specific structure. Each paragraph has a specific thing it is supposed to report about.
- Paragraphs are usually 1-2 sentences long.
- The entire report is typically a half page long, but could be as long as three pages.
- The reports are plain text. The formatting is handled by our inventory management system.

## Requirements

- The program can be trained using the text from our half million existing reports.
- The program continues to learn from the reports we write and the phrases users are likely to accept.
- The program's learning takes place on a company-wide level, not at the user level, so predictive typing improves for everyone. This probably means a web app or server-side software.
- The program has a interface where management can block phrases they want to stop appearing in reports.
- The program has a built-in feedback tool that lets users hit a key to flag bad phrases to make them stop showing up. The bad phrases stop showing up for that user, and are reported to management for review.
- The program can be operated exclusively using the keyboard. No need to touch the mouse.
- Cost: maybe $2500 for a perpetual, company-wide license? I might be able to get approval for more if it's something really phenomenal.

## What I have looked at

- Most of our users keep a separate document with commonly-used phrases they can copy and paste into their report, changing just a word or two as needed. The software you recommend would make this practice obsolete.
- One person started using [PhraseExpress](https://www.phraseexpress.com/) a few years ago and loved it, so we recommended it to everyone, but so far I only know of three people (out of 500) who have started using it. It seems the learning curve is too steep (80% of our associates are independent contractors, so we can only suggest they use the software, not require it). It's really more of a clipboard manager than predictive typing software. It requires the user to manage their own phrases and type abbreviations to insert a phrase, rather than suggesting phrases based on context and previous usage. I expect that something that adds on to what the user is already doing would have a much higher adoption rate.
- [Lightkey](https://www.lightkey.io/editions) sounds good, but it sounds like its "collective wisdom" feature is a [new feature that's not mature yet](https://www.lightkey.io/post/lightkey-for-business-the-power-of-collective-wisdom). It's not clear if it has a management interface or not. It's a bit out of budget, but I could probably get approval for it if it strongly meets our requirements.
- [Typing Assistant](https://www.sumitsoft.com/features.htm) and [FastKeys](https://www.fastkeysautomation.com/index.html) seem to be for a single user, not an organization. They don't seem to have a way to share their learning.
- [Other programs](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60998-autocomplete-12/) I looked at only suggested a single word, instead of suggesting whole phrases.

## Related questions

#### Predictive text for personal use

These questions are about predictive text for a single user, not for company-wide predictive text.

- [Text editor with word suggestion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28323/text-editor-with-word-suggestion)
- [Software which autocompletes frequently typed words/phrases in Ubuntu or at least Firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4184/software-which-autocompletes-frequently-typed-words-phrases-in-ubuntu-or-at-leas)
- [Is there any text editor with autocomplete?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/is-there-any-text-editor-with-autocomplete)

#### Sharing report formatting company-wide

This question is about sharing formatting for reports, not about sharing phrases used in reports.

- [Professional report writing software options](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19184/professional-report-writing-software-options)